# How to convert base64 encoded string to JSON String

Tags: android, json, base64, okhttp

It is my first android application in which I am uploading an image on a server.I am using okhttp3 library to send base64 encoded string to server.

Before I send this encoded string, I am printing this in logcat and decoding through online base64 to image converter and getting the same image BUT when I am converting this string to JSON string, I can only see partial base64 encoded string.

I have tried to find this answer on internet but didn't get any solution.

Here is my code,

```
class Background extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    //getting base64 encoded string from Main Activity
    String encoded_string = new MainActivity().encoded_string;

    String image_name="Hello.jpg";

    Context context;
    String TAG = "Background";
    Background(Context c) {
        context=c;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+encoded_string); // Here I can see complete base64 encoded string

        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
        String jsonString=null;
        try {
            jsonObject.put("image_name",image_name);
            jsonObject.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
            jsonString=jsonObject.toString();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: "+jsonString);  // But here I am getting partial encoded string in JSON.

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient=new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody= new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("jsonString",jsonString)
                .build();

        Request request=new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://b1b8540f.ngrok.io/feedthecow/uploadImage.php")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        String responseIntoString=null;
        try {
            Response response=okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
            responseIntoString=response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseIntoString;
    }
}
```

Comment: _I can only see partial base64 encoded string_. Where?

Comment: In logcat @KNeerajLal

Comment: Is your image uploading?

Comment: Yes, but because app is sending a partial encoded string, a completely black image I am receiving on the server side. @KNeerajLal

Comment: @KNeerajLal I am not getting why this encoded string is not being converted into complete JSON data. Is there any limit like only upto certain characters of string can be converted into JSON data not whole ?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. :)

Comment: `new MainActivity().encoded_string` gives you the `encoded_string`? Did you debug if it is complete?

Comment: Yes,I  have declared "encoded_string " as a public static in Main Activity and I am getting it @KNeerajLal

Comment: Ty `echo` what you are getting at the server. Is it complete?

Comment: No, getting partial encoded string @KNeerajLal

Comment: Logcat has size limitation. May be only the output is truncated? Better save the strings into a file and loop at the data there.

Comment: @Robert You are right. Due to size limitation of logcat, I wasn't able to see complete data. Thanks :)